# Independent Events problem

Tags: probability

I got this problem:

> There is a contest where prizes $A$ and $B$ will be raffled. There is a $15\%$ chance of winning prize $A$ and a $7\%$ chance of winning prize $B$. Each prize will be raffled individually and these events are independent.
>
> What is the probability of winning at least one of these prizes?

The solution is supposed to be $0.2095$ or $20.95%$, but I can't seem to figure out how. I am doing $0.15+(0.15*0.07)+0.07$ and that gives me $0.2305$ or $23.05\%$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what happens if the probability of winning each prize is $50\%$ and $75\%$, respectively.  According to your formula, the probability of winning at least one prize is $$0.5 + (0.5)(0.75) + 0.75 > 1,$$ which is clearly absurd.

On the other hand, what is the probability of winning **neither** prize?  This can be calculated by first determining the probability of not winning each prize, which would be $1 - 0.5 = 0.5$ for $A$, and $1 - 0.75 = 0.25$ for $B$.  Then the chance of not winning either prize is $$(0.5)(0.25) = 0.125.$$  So, with $1/8$ probability, you could fail to win anything, meaning that with $7/8 = 0.875$ probability, you would win *something*.

This illustrates how we could solve the original question:  we would calculate instead $$1 - (1 - 0.15)(1 - 0.07),$$ and this would be the desired result.

Why did your formula not work?  Well, clearly there is something wrong with adding up probabilities to the point where they exceed $1$.  The issue here is that the addition of probabilities should only be allowed when the events associated with them cannot simultaneously occur.  Here, you've added up $\Pr[A]$ and $\Pr[B]$, where $A$ and $B$ are the events of winning prize $A$ and prize $B$, respectively.  But you could win both, and in such an event, adding $\Pr[A] + \Pr[B]$ will **double count** the probability associated with winning both.  You then exacerbate this problem by adding yet again $\Pr[A \cap B]$, so now you've **triple counted** this event.

This illustrates that what you should have done was compute $$\Pr[A] + \Pr[B] - \Pr[A \cap B] = 0.15 + 0.07 - (0.15)(0.07).$$  Does this equal the other method of calculation, $1 - (1 - 0.15)(1 - 0.07)$?  Why does it work both ways?

The underlying formula that is being used here is $$\Pr[A \cup B] = \Pr[A] + \Pr[B] - \Pr[A \cap B].$$  This is true regardless of whether $A$ and $B$ are independent events.

Answer (score 1):

> Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion (two-set case):
>
> $$P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

Letting $A$ represent the event of winning prize $A$ and $B$ be the event of winning prize $B$, we have by the independence assumption that

$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A)\cdot P(B)$

$ = 0.15+0.07 - 0.15\cdot 0.07 = 0.2095$

You added instead of subtracted.